# Set hive variables based on condition

Tags: hive, bigdata, data-ingestion

I want to set hive variables based on condition. I am not sure if that's possible in HQL or not and if it is possible then how to achieve that.

I want to do something like this,

```
if ${hiveconf:work}==1 then do
    set q1 = 4;
    set yr2 = eval(${hiveconf:year}-1);
    set q3= 3;
end
else if ${hiveconf:work}==2 then do
    set q2 = 4;
    set yr1 = eval(${hiveconf:year}-2);
    set q4= 2;
end
```

Any help and knowledge will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of settring variable, you could try using a CASE statement in your request depending upon ${hiveconf:work}

Comment: okay. so you are saying to convert it like case below:

`case
 when ${hiveconf:work}=1  then q1 = 4
 when ${hiveconf:work}=1  then yr2= eval(${hiveconf:year}-1)
 when ${hiveconf:work}=1  then q3 = 3
else
 when ${hiveconf:work}=2 then q2 = 4
 when ${hiveconf:work}=2 then yr2= eval(${hiveconf:year}-2)
 when ${hiveconf:work}=2 then q4 = 2;
end`
<br/>

I have 2 doubts in this:
1. I have seen using CASE in SELECT statement mostly. So will it work this way just to set variables?
2. Can this redundancy of using ${hiveconf:work}=1 be minimized?

Comment: One more question. is it possible to set a variable in case statement like below?
`- when ${hiveconf:quarter2}=3 then set q2=1`

Comment: No, what I meant is to NOT use variables y1, q2 and q4 and adapt the rest of your code with CASE statements

Comment: can you add the queries that you want to run after set the variables?